Проблема с подключением заголовочного файла С++
Как подключить заголовочник, если он не в том же месте что и main.cpp или даже не в папке проекта?
Где указывается путь дополнительных включаемых файлов?
Попытался подключить в c_cpp_properties.json используя разные слеши:
"includePath": [              
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "m:\\test\\include",
                "m:/test/include",
                "m://test//include"

но все равно не помогло.
main.cpp лежит в test;
header.h расположил в include;
в main.cpp пишу:
#include "header.h"

Что-то вы бежите вперед паравоза. Ковыряние с плагинами c++ в visual studio code требуют наличия навыков обращения с компилятором и сопутствующим инструментарием. т.е. вы должны уметь собрать самостоятельно печатая команды в консоли. Если еще не умеете, начните например с https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170
